# PHP & Google Maps Postcode Checker

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

> I'm not asking for anybody to build the application for me. I'm just looking for some direction. Plugins, Tutorials, etc.

How would I go around making a small application to check if a custom is within our operating radius?

So when a customer starts the ordering process, they will be asked to give us their postcode and they enter their their postcode so that we can check it. So if it is outwith our operating boundaries of 50 miles from another postcode then we will display a static error message and tell them to check back later.

By the way this is UK postcodes.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you only want to operate within 50 miles radius of your store?

Comment: @frosy yes - we want to provide a service 50 miles from our workyard.

Comment: Do you have the list of postal codes that are within 50 miles from your workyard?

Comment: No we were hoping to use the google maps api

Comment: Do you know about cURL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91927/discussion-between-rra-webteam-and-frosty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get all US Zipcodes or UK Postcodes within whatever radius use this tool...

- For **US**:
  http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm
- For
  **UK**: http://www.freemaptools.com/find-uk-postcodes-inside-radius.htm

> For any other tools you can try and check [this site](http://www.freemaptools.com)